# how to open .sqlite file when it was created with firefox plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I created my table and inserted my data with firefox sqlite manager extension,saved and added my sqlitefile which is "notifications.sqlite" after that I wrote this code but it will output me **nothing**.

is there any difference between opening .sqlite file and .db file? how can I open my database properly?

**UPDATE:**after debugging as the friend commented it has problem in this line:

```
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"notifications.sqlite"]];
```

after

```
  if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == YES)
```

the if is NOT YES so it will lost everything so the databasePath is sort of wrong

my table is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE "quotes_type" ("type_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "content" VARCHAR)
```

and here is my effort to open the .sqlite file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

  NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"notifications.sqlite"]];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == YES)
    {
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *qrycount = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select * from quotes_type"];

        const char *count_stmt = [qrycount UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, count_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ERROR) {
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error when selecting rows  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        } else {
              NSLog(@"negin");
            int myid=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];
            NSLog(@"myid is %d",myid);
            NSLog(@"text is %@",text);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(contactDB);
        }
    }
    else NSLog(@"openning has problem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger to check which statement exactly fails? Why don't you use `sqlite3_errmsg()` to report error messages instead of just "opening has problems"?

Comment: I used it once that it will go to the open statement the problem is somewhere after sqlite_open because I don't have any nslog output

Comment: I edited my question but simultaneously it seems someone was editing me and I lost it I appologize

Comment: @nikparsa You say your friend says that setting of `databasePath` is incorrect. It's inefficient, but not wrong. But you could more simply do `databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"notifications.sqlite"];`. But that's not the problem.

Comment: Martin Told me to debug when I debugged I realized that the  if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == YES) is not YES and it will lost everything

Comment: Yes, that's simply because the database (assuming you've added it to your bundle) is in the bundle. But you're looking in the documents folder and simply doing nothing if it's not found. If you want to open that database, if not found in Documents, you'd want to copy it from the bundle to Documents.

Comment: ahaaaaa yes yes maybe that's the problem thanks

Comment: @Rob I don't know bundle exactly I just added the file would you please let me know how to add the Bundle?

Comment: `NSString *bundleDbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notifications" ofType:@"sqlite"];`

Comment: @Rob yes you were absolutely right Thank you so much.I have another problem now I will try to solve it myself please answer the question so I can choose it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for the database in `Documents`. But did you ever copy it there? If not, you'll never find it there. You really want to check for the file and if not found, copy it from the bundle to the `Documents` folder. Thus, if you don't find the database in `Documents`, you should copy it via:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *bundleDatabasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notifications" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSAssert(bundleDatabasePath, @"database not found in bundle");
if (![filemgr copyItemAtPath:bundleDatabasePath toPath:databasePath error:&error])
    NSLog(@"%s: copyItemAtPath failure: error = %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FMDB to manage your sqlite db, It's pretty easy.

github:[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)